# Why does it sound wrong to my ears when someone says a thing "is aesthetic"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Off the top of my head, this is a few of the ways I've heard the word aesthetic used to describe a thing:

1. This thing is aesthetically pleasing.
2. This thing has a nice aesthetic.
3. I like the aesthetics of this thing.

And then there's this one that I've been hearing more of lately:

4. This thing is aesthetic.

To my ears, 4 sounds wrong. I may be misunderstanding the meaning of aesthetic, but it sounds weird to say that a thing *is itself aesthetic*. I think people who say this are using the incorrect word, as if they meant to say a thing is visually pleasing but then swapped it out for aesthetic. I do, however, realize that it's a correct sentence. Why does this sound incorrect when just saying something *is* visually pleasing or *is* beautiful or *is* pretty is not?

Comment: Because it looks. :P

Comment: Before commenting on the acceptability of a word, construction etc, we should realise that subjectiveness is universal, and if possible check (in a dictionary here) to see whether **we**'re likely to be the one out of step. Other than OED and Webster's, reputable dictionaries list senses in order of assessed idiomaticity (how often their researchers find senses being used), which is often a valuable resource. Google Ngram searches (for 'it is aesthetic' vs  'it is aesthetically pleasing', say) will also provide valuable pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This thing is aesthetic* only tells us that the thing has something to do with aesthetics. Often such a sentence conveys that the thing serves some aesthetic function, that it is intended for some aesthetic purpose, **without implying anything** as to whether the thing serves that function well, as to whether it actually accomplishes the purpose.

For example, suppose that I am explaining to someone how to use a certain gadget, and that after saying 'you use the red thing to turn on the gadget, the blue one to adjust the volume . . .', I am asked 'What about the yellow thing?' The answer may be 'The yellow thing is purely aesthetic'. That would mean that the designers of the gadget intended its yellow component to somehow improve its appearance. In saying this, I would not be implying that the yellow thing actually improves the appearance of the gadget; my saying that it is aesthetic conveys only what it is intended for, and is compatible with my thinking that the thing actually uglifies the gadget.

In this respect, *this thing is aesthetic* is different from the other three examples in the question, which all convey some kind of a positive reaction to the thing.

Comment: Somehow I'd forgotten the usage of it that you brought up. I've heard "This is just for aesthetics" or some variation of it before, and that sounds perfectly correct. I think you've hit on why "This is aesthetic" sounds incorrect to me, because it is a completely different meaning than the other three scenarios. I assume most people who say "This is aesthetic" mean "This thing _has good_ aesthetics", and so it sounds jarring because what they're really saying is "This thing's purpose has to do with aesthetics".

Answer (score 2):

If you take the dictionary definitions such as [the Lexico one](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aesthetic)

> 1.1 Giving or designed to give pleasure through beauty.

without looking at the examples it is difficult to argue against the use of "this dishwasher is aesthetic" but the examples of use  such as the one for the Lexico entry above which is:

> the law applies to both functional and aesthetic objects

all point to more general or abstract applications.

The use of 'aesthetic' to describe an object directly jars with me as well, not least because it sounds pretentious. But it seems that 'aesthetic' has only been accepted properly as an English word for about 150 years and the direct description use has been around for quite a while so I'm afraid, as Eliot implies in his answer, that we're just going to have to accept it as an organic change to the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have unconsciously given structural bias to your examples, and this tends to confirm your argument that "aesthetic" produces a strange sounding predicative adjective/complement.

1938   Amer. Home Jan. 21/2   *The days when grandmamma put a million photographs on the wall in close array and thought the result aesthetic.*

1881   W. S. Gilbert Patience i. 22   *I am a broken-hearted troubadour, Whose mind's æsthetic, and whose tastes are pure.*

1945   I. Gershwin Alessandro the Wise (song) in Lyrics on Several Occasions (1959) 334   *Refrain. I'm aesthetic, poetic; To beauty I'm sympathetic. Soldiers. A patron of the arts is Alessandro.*

2020 Greybeard WRF "He dismissed the design, which I had considered aesthetic, as being too complicated."

Comment: The above being a corrective rather than just reverse bias? But _how often_ is the adjectival usage found in comparison to the adverbial etc?

Comment: aesthetic_ADJ,aesthetically https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=aesthetic_ADJ%2Caesthetically&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caesthetic_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caesthetically%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone in your concerns about the seeming trivialisation of the word (or words in the lexeme) *aesthetic*. Gabriel Lipkowitz, a junior concentrator in molecular biology at Princeton University (and author of at least one well received critique on architectural design) has written an article on the subject.

> - The Problem with Calling Something “Aesthetic”
>
> by Gabriel E. Lipkowitz on March 3, 2019
>
> “Oh, that’s so aesthetic.”
>
> It’s a slang expression I’ve heard being thrown around increasing
> frequently, over the past year, by us college students (Princeton
> being no exception). To be more specific: “aesthetic” used in this way
> acts as a stand-alone adjective, in itself describing something.
> Sometimes this “something” is an object: I have heard us call a glass
> filled with different colors of sand “aesthetic”; or a Bosai tree in a
> small pot with even smaller stones; or many other similar objects
> found in one’s local Starbucks.  Other times I have heard a building
> or room called “aesthetic”: perhaps a dimly lit bar established in a
> revitalized factory. Still other times, I’ve heard a model’s clothing
> described as “aesthetic,” like that advertised on huge posters at the
> Gap.
>
> Despite, or perhaps due to, this ubiquity, I find it very difficult to
> pinpoint what exactly we mean by calling something “aesthetic.”
> Certainly, it suggests some general concern with visual appearance,
> but what do we actually communicate to another person when we describe
> something as “aesthetic”? Many slang words or expressions lack
> concrete definitions, of course, but here I argue that there is
> something particularly insidious about our lapse into imprecise and
> cursory uses of aesthetics. Such is a theoretical argument with
> important implications for assessing our generation’s perception and
> interpretation of built and unbuilt environments.
>
> The central problem with our present usage of “aesthetic,” I argue, is
> its omission of nearly all meaning traditionally associated with the
> otherwise very meaningful term. Aesthetics, of course, is as complex
> and historical a topic as there is, dating back at least to the Greeks
> and frequently referenced in the academic literature on a variety of
> humanistic topics. To explain these traditional meanings, I will not
> myself attempt a definition, a task for which I am hardly prepared.
> Rather, I will refer to the widely acclaimed and relatively recent
> book The Hand and the Soul(2009), which provides an excellent
> introduction to the topic in the form of essays written by thirteen
> architects, artists, and philosophers. These can provide the lens
> through which we can see the inadequacies that arise from our
> colloquialization of the term today.... The lack of either discussion
> or elaboration following our colloquial usage of “aesthetic” today is
> the first indication of trouble. For rarely when we call an object or
> space “aesthetic” does discussion or description go anything beyond
> that. Instead, without any elaboration, “aesthetic” becomes synonymous
> with mere “prettiness,” taking on the characteristics of cheap
> associations that lack the depth typically accorded to the term.
>
> Leaving aside the cognitive facet of aesthetics, a second issue arises
> with how our present use of the term treats perception itself. Namely,
> it places dominant—perhaps exclusive—focus on purely visual
> perception. Yet a true aesthetic experience, as the artist and
> architect Sanda Iliescu points out in The Hand and the Soul, requires
> extra-visual perceptions including smell, touch, and temperature, and
> many others. “[A]esthetic experiences awaken all our sense
> perceptions,” she explains. Some might claim that calling something
> “aesthetic” does not necessarily preclude such extra-visual
> perceptions. Highly unlikely, I would say, given the rapidity, almost
> instinctiveness, with which we designate an object or place with that
> term. We walk into a room, or see an object, and immediately call it
> “aesthetic,” but to engage in a complex multisensory experience, and
> discern relationships between diverse perceptions, requires both more
> attention and time than we are affording it right now. A truly
> “aesthetic experience,” as Iliescu writes, requires us to “slow down
> our sense of time.” (Sadly, this is a skill our instant
> anything-obsessed generation seems to lack anyways…)
>
> A third traditionally meaningful aspect of aesthetics neglected by our
> present usage is its subjectivity. In describing the “aesthetic
> experience,” Iliescu explains that “each aesthetic experience is
> unique and tied to a specific place, time, and individual.” Indeed,
> one need not be an artist like Iliescu to appreciate the importance of
> subjectivity in art making and interpretation. Not so according to our
> present colloquial usage of the term, in which individuals, by laying
> down the immutable, binary categorization of a thing as “aesthetic,”
> erase, or at least severely downplay, personal ambiguity and
> subjectivity another person should confront when viewing an object.
> Something is not aesthetic according to me, one pronounces; rather, it
> is aesthetic, period....

An opinion. One I subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

The word aesthetic is normally used in a tertiary, third hand, form. It is no wonder that it rankles your sensibilities when it is used in a first or second hand form. I feel the same way plus or minus 1/2. In a world that uses the words in ways we cannot escape or demand improvement on we must take what is on offer.

Comment: What exactly is a first/second/third hand form?